# Autofilling a form with data from a different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm currently working on a website with multiple pages.  On one of the pages is a form that produces a table.  Id like it to be that if I click on a cell in the table (just one column) that it would take me to another one of my pages with a form on it, and autofill the input element with the data that was in that cell I had clicked on.  I couldn't think of a way to do this since they are two different pages and have two different scripts so the data doesn't persist.  Right now, I just have it so that my PHP script creates links to that other page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can send the ID to the next page and make a query over there
- You can Store the data in the SESSION

For the first way 
just use `$_GET['id']` and make query using it 
in the table page use

```
<a href="url.php?id=your_id">Click</a>
```

For the 2nd way 
You can have to set the `SESSION` first then you can use it

**But the first way is what you are looking for**